# Validação condicional em componente PrimeFaces

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf, primefaces

Olá!

Estou com o seguinte problema. Tenho o inputText descrição que fica desabilitado por default. Quando clico no botão pesquisar, ele habilita o inputText e logo instância um objeto para pesquisa. Se eu não passar um filtro no inputText descrição, ele pesquisa todos os registros do objeto que estou usando, se eu passar um filtro ele traz os registros de acordo com o filtro informado. Na minha classe tenho uma anotação @NotNull na propriedade descrição, para tratar a validação na tela de cadastro, porém para evitar que o inputText seja validado na hora de pesquisar sem nenhum filtro, estou utilizando em meu commandButton o process="@this", mas se eu passar um filtro, esse filtro não está sendo "setado" na propriedade descrição do meu objeto e está sempre pesquisando todos registros.

Como eu trato essa situação ? Se eu retirar a anotação de minha propriedade a lógica funciona corretamente, mas se eu utiliza-la fico com esse problema.

Estou utilizando as anotações do Bean Validations para não ter que fazer uma validação dentro do meu bean criando um serie de if e else, com o Bean Validations acredito que estarei tratando as validações na fase correta do ciclo de vida.

Códigos das páginas!

**Template CRUD basic.xhtml (Código 1)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
  <title>${titulo}</title>
  <h:outputStylesheet name="core.js" target="head" library="js" />
  <h:outputStylesheet name="style.css" target="head" library="css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>

  <div id="dvStatus" align="center">
    <p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show();" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide();" />
    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
      <p:graphicImage value="/resources/img/icon/ajaxloading3.gif" />
    </p:dialog>
  </div>

  <h:form id="formCrud">
    <ui:insert name="cabecalho">
      <ui:include src="tmenu.xhtml" />
    </ui:insert>

    <p:toolbar/>

    <ui:insert name="toolbar">
      <p:toolbar id="tool">
        <p:toolbarGroup>
          <ui:insert name="toolbarButtons" />
        </p:toolbarGroup>
      </p:toolbar>
    </ui:insert>

    <ui:insert name="panelExterno">
      <ui:insert name="panelCentral" />
      <center>
        <h:messages id="growl" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" showSummary="false" errorClass="converterMsgError" warnClass="converterMsgWarn" infoClass="converterMsgInfo" fatalClass="converterMsgError" />
      </center>
    </ui:insert>

    <p:confirmDialog global="true">
      <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="confirm" />
      <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="cancel" />
    </p:confirmDialog>
  </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

**Template CRUD crud.xhtml (Código 2)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/templates/basic.xhtml">

  <ui:define name="toolbarButtons">
    <ui:insert name="btnNew">
      <p:commandButton id="new" value="Novo" actionListener="#{backingBean.novo}" update="tool pnlCampos growl" disabled="#{backingBean.disableBtnNew}" icon="novo" style="width:100px; margin-left: 6px;" />
    </ui:insert>
    <ui:insert name="btnSave">
      <p:commandButton id="save" value="Salvar" actionListener="#{backingBean.salvar}" update="tool pnlCampos pnlTable growl" disabled="#{backingBean.disableBtnSave}" icon="gravar" style="width:100px;margin-left: 6px;" />
    </ui:insert>
    <ui:insert name="btnCancel">
      <p:commandButton id="cancel" value="Cancelar" actionListener="#{backingBean.cancelar}" process="@this" update="tool pnlCampos pnlTable growl" disabled="#{backingBean.disableBtnCancel}" icon="cancel" style="width:100px;margin-left: 6px;" />
    </ui:insert>
    <ui:insert name="btnFind">
      <p:commandButton id="search" value="Pesquisar" actionListener="#{backingBean.pesquisar}" process="@this pnlCampos" update="tool pnlCampos pnlTable growl" disabled="#{backingBean.disableBtnSearch}" icon="search" style="width:100px;margin-left: 6px;" />
    </ui:insert>
    <ui:insert name="btnExport" />
    <ui:insert name="toolbarExtraButtons" />
  </ui:define>

  <ui:define name="panelCentral">
    <ui:insert name="panelDeCadastro">
      <p:panel id="pnlCampos" header="${toolTitulo}">
        <ui:insert name="panelCadastro" />
      </p:panel>
    </ui:insert>
    <ui:insert name="table">
      <p:outputPanel id="pnlTable" deferred="true">
        <p:dataTable id="table" value="#{backingBean.model}" var="obj" rows="8" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" emptyMessage="" rowStyleClass="#{empty rowIx or rowIx mod 2 ne 0 ? 'even-row' : 'odd-row'}" rowIndexVar="rowIx" scrollable="true">
          <f:facet name="header">
            Registro(s) Cadastrado(s)
          </f:facet>
          <ui:insert name="colunasTabela" />

          <p:column id="edit" style="width: 10px; text-align:center;">
            <p:commandLink title="Editar Registro" actionListener="#{backingBean.editar}" process="@this" update=":formCrud:pnlCampos :formCrud:tool :formCrud:pnlTable :formCrud:growl">
              <p:graphicImage value="/resources/img/icon/editar_16x16.png" />
            </p:commandLink>
          </p:column>
          <p:column id="del" style="width: 10px; text-align:center;">
            <p:commandLink title="Deletar Registro" actionListener="#{backingBean.excluir}" process="@this" update=":formCrud:pnlCampos :formCrud:tool :formCrud:pnlTable :formCrud:growl">
              <p:graphicImage value="/resources/img/icon/excluir_16x16.png" />
              <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{backingBean.rowData}" value="#{obj}" />
              <p:confirm header="Atenção" message="Você confirma a exclusão desse registro ?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
            </p:commandLink>
          </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
      </p:outputPanel>
    </ui:insert>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**Tela de Cadastro de Cargo (Código 3)**

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition template="/templates/crud.xhtml">

  <ui:param name="titulo" value="Tela de Cargo" />
  <ui:param name="toolTitulo" value="Cadastro e Edição de Cargo" />
  <ui:param name="backingBean" value="#{cargoBean}" />

  <ui:define name="panelCadastro">
    <h:panelGrid id="pnlGrdCargo" columns="1" width="100%">
      <h:outputText value="Descrição:" />

      <p:inputText value="#{cargoBean.domain.descricao}" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" disabled="#{cargoBean.disabledOnDefault}" style="width: 30%;" />
    </h:panelGrid>
  </ui:define>

  <ui:define name="colunasTabela">
    <p:column headerText="Código" style="width: 50px;">
      <h:outputText value="#{obj.codigoCargoFuncionario}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Descrição">
      <h:outputText value="#{obj.descricao}" />
    </p:column>
  </ui:define>

</ui:composition>

</html>
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu botão de pesquisar não esta processando o campo descrição.

Você tem duas opções para resolver.

**1º:** 
Processar o inputText pelo seu botão

```
<p:commandButton id="search" value="Pesquisar" actionListener="#{backingBean.pesquisar}" process="@this ID_DO_INPUT" update="tool pnlCampos pnlTable growl" disabled="#{backingBean.disableBtnSearch}" icon="search" style="width:100px;margin-left: 6px;" />
```

**2º:**
Quando alterar a descrição mandar ele processar

```
<p:inputText value="#{cargoBean.domain.descricao}" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" disabled="#{cargoBean.disabledOnDefault}" style="width: 30%;" >
        <p:ajax event="change" process="@this"/>
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Rafael. Vou testar as duas opções e posto os resultados.

Comment: Rafael obrigado pela ajuda, testei e funcionou corretamente as duas opções, mas estou utilizando a segunda porque tenho uma camada genérica de CRUD que é usada em várias telas, então a segunda opção foi mais viável. Obrigado.

Comment: De nada, qualquer coisa só avisar.

Comment: Rafael tudo bem. Como informei as duas formas que você citou funciona corretamente, porém utilizando a 2 forma "*que é a que estou usando*", verifiquei que vou ter que realizar esse processamento parcial com @this em todos inputText de todas telas de cadastro onde é usado meu template de CRUD genérico. Então estou tentando usar a primeira forma que você falou, mas não está dando certo, sempre está caindo na validação do campo. Editei minha pergunta adicionando minhas telas genéricas de CRUD completas e a tela principal de cadastro que estou utilizando.

Comment: Eu retirei do meu inputText descrição da tela de cadastro de cargo (Código 3) a 2 opção que o Rafael informou e usei a 1 opção no meu commandButton Pesquisar (Código 2) do template de CRUD.xhtml, passando @this e o id do panel que está dentro do ui:define panelCentral e ui:insert panelDeCadastro que contém os inputText de cadastro. Mas não deu certo.